# Why does ast.literal_eval() seem to ignore declared variables?

Tags: python, dictionary, eval

I have heard that ast.literal_eval is much safer than eval(), but while changing my code, I am getting 'malformed string/node' errors.

For example:

```
bar = False
incorrect = {"foo":bar}
correct = {"foo":"bar"}

ast.literal_eval(incorrect)
```

returns the error but

```
ast.literal_eval(correct)
```

returns the expected {"foo":"bar"}

Why doesn't the first evaluation return {"foo":False}

Comment: Maybe you want to put quotes around your dictionaries, because otherwise why bother with eval? `literal_eval('{"foo":"bar"}')` works as expected.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to ensure that no malicious code passes into the program, but I guess literal_eval does just that, evaluates only literals. Is there another alternative better than eval() that takes into account other values, or is what I am asking for a contradiction?

Comment: Are you trying to validate user input from say, a website form or something similar? If so, this is not the correct way unfortunately. Using `eval` is a *great* way to make sure some malicious code will pass into your program.

Comment: Yes, kind of, I'm trying to read a dictionary formatted API. What's the correct way to go about this?

Comment: Sounds a lot like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON for which you can `import json` and work from there.

Comment: Yes! That seems right, but when I tried to ask a question about grabbing JSON from an online API/webpage and was told that I wasn't using JSON. I'll look into it again, thank you. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it is not meant to do that. From the documentation:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded
>   string containing a Python expression. The string or node provided may
>   only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings,
>   numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

`ast.literal_eval` and `eval` are meant to turn a string representation of python code into ...valid python code.

This will not work:

```
>>> ast.literal_eval({"foo": "bar"})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string <-- Telltale right here.
```

That is because you already have a valid python structure which you are attempting to evaluate.

If you put quotes around the whole thing instead, it will create a dictionary:

```
>>> ast.literal_eval('{"foo": "bar"}')
{'foo': 'bar'}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)
on ast.literal_eval:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python expression. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python expressions from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself.

`bar` is indeed `False`, but is not *literal*. `literal_eval` cannot see variables. It only works with literals.