# Keeping strings in ast.literal_eval to dict

Tags: python

If I use `literal_eval` on some strings to get a dictionary, it works fine:

```
import ast

string = '{123: True, 456: False}'

In: ast.literal_eval(string)
Out: {123: True, 456: False}
```

But if the string has a string within it, I get an error:

```
string = '{123: Foo, 456: Bar}'

In: ast.literal_eval(string)
Out: ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x7f7d5faae9e8>
```

How can I keep strings in the second `literal_eval`?

Comment: Those aren't strings.  In the code `{123: Foo, 456: Bar}`, `Foo` and `Bar` are python objects.  Did you mean `{123: "Foo", 456: "Bar"}`?

Comment: @RishiG: They're not Python objects, they're interpreted as the names or identifiers of objects.

Comment: Similar question asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235419/why-does-ast-literal-eval-seem-to-ignore-declared-variables?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you gave, i.e.

```py
{123: Foo, 456: Bar}
```

does not contain strings. It contains identifiers `Foo` and `Bar`.

A correct string would rather look like:

```py
{123: "Foo", 456: "Bar"}
```

That's why AST module try to parse, does not see expected literal (number of string), and panics because it sees some identifier. Does that help?

P.S. Thanks @RishiG for pointing out redundant backslashes.

Comment: You don't need the backslashes.

Comment: Technically, `Foo` and `Bar` are not literals, they are names - in the AST they're represented by `Name` objects. A literal is an expression which has a fixed value independent of any other code. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)

Comment: I believe @snapcrack had strings inside (i.e., "if the string has a string inside"). Otherwise, you are right, Foo and Bar would be identifiers for some Python objects.

Comment: `Foo` and `Bar` are interpreted as Python _names_ (aka identifiers), not [literal values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)).

Comment: Yes, I changed it now. I did not initially get what you meant.

Comment: Thanks. This was honestly not a terribly well worded question on my part, but this definitely answers it as written.